# UITableView scrolling crashes app

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

When i scroll UITableView it crashes the app. Here is code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *tempDict = [albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 
} else {
    AsyncImageView *oldImage = (AsyncImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
    [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I set the breakpoints and it stops at line

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this `tempDict` var for ??

Comment: Is your "albums" an array of dictionaries as many as your rows?

Comment: Can you please give me some idea about your table's features?

Comment: album is of type NSArray. From that i wrote code NSDictionary *tempDict = [albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; to get the object in NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Actually in the $cellForRow ,I was trying to get information from server, I did not apply lazy loading there. Because of that while scrolling the tableView, app was crashing.

Thank you to all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, first of all please check the total number of rows and your array count. They must be same. If still it crashes then put this line

```
NSDictionary *tempDict = [[albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] copy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check size of **albums** array. May be it is smaller then indexPath.row or it was released somewhere.

Comment: size of albums array is 3. And from that i retrieve the NSDictionary *tempDict = [albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: How many cells do you want to display? What does return `numberOfRowsInSection`? Try to add `NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row)` before `..tempDict = ..`. What will be printed?

Comment: number of rows should be equal to [albums count]. And NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row) gives me 0,1,2. And my [albums count] also returns 3.

Comment: Try to comment `else {...}`. Is it still crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not reading out of bounds of your NSdictionary.

Check your return value in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` dataSource method.

Comment: album is of type NSArray. From that i wrote code NSDictionary *tempDict = [albums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; to get the object in NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for a crash on that line is that your table view has more rows than you have items in your albums array. Normally, in a setup like this, you'd have exactly the same number of rows in your table, and your implementation of –tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: would look like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // assuming that there is only one section
    return [albums count];
}
```